# (HTML) PNG on top of another PNG - possible to eliminate full transparency?

Tags: html, png, transparency

I'd like to put a logo png onto of another coloured png. They both have transparent backgrounds. When I try this the images blend together. Curiously, in Photoshop the logo  retains its opaque-ness - I put colours on the layers underneath it, another image, etc etc, the logo is still opaque.

I'd like to do it this way so I can rotate the background images.

How do I fix this?

[edit]I've cooked up an example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdKNB.png

The left is what I want to happen, the right is what happens on all browsers (I know the background isn't transparent but bear with me - they're both transparent pngs, with the background having a gradient layer mask). I've put the images like this

```
<div>
    <img id="backgroundImg" style="position: absolute; top: 0;" src="/Images/background.png" />
    <img id="logoImg" src="/Images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure what blending mode I'm using in PS.

I've made two test PNGs if anyone wants to try. 
abload.de/img/flagf25ea.png 
abload.de/img/logo9k4ol.png

Comment: I don't understand the problem, could you post an image?

Comment: What type of blending do you use in Photoshop? Your browser only supports 'normal' blending.
What do you mean with 'transparant backgrounds'? Is it an alpha channel or just 100% transparency?

Comment: Is it an option to remove the transparency in the original image? seems easiest to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - the issue was with z-indexes - I didn't specify them for **both** the images. Set the index of the logo to be higher than the background and the pngs won't blend with each other.

[edit]Whups, it turns out that `position:absolute` must also be applied in the styles.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when designers layer things with PhotoShop. You can't use blend modes when layering individual images, instead of PhotoShop Layers.

You will need to make your design work in PhotoShop without using blend modes on the layers so that when you stack the layers individually, they will look the same. You probably have the 'LOGO" layer set to something like 'Lighten' or 'Multiply'. It needs to look right while set to 'Normal' before you can take out the individual layers and overlay them as images

Comment: I see what you all mean by Blending Mode now (I've always just called them "Layer Adjustments"). The issue with that is I'm using Normal layers so Blending modes doesn't appear to be the problem here.

Comment: Are you using opacity or anything else that wouldn't save out? In order to stack images like this, each of the layers would have to look correct independent of all of the other layers.

Comment: http://www.abload.de/img/flagf25ea.png
http://www.abload.de/img/logo9k4ol.png

These are my two test pngs. The flag had a gradient layer mask applied on it, that's all I've done to it. The logo is text with the background layer in PS removed.